# SBS 2011 Log file

Tags: sharepoint

Every morning the SBS 2011 sends me the same error log, I need to understand if there is a way to solve all the errors. I often read on different blogs that these errors are not important, here they are, thanks for you help:

```
enter code here
```

Event Source    Event ID    Last Occurence  Total Occurences

WinRM           142         28/08/2012 07:30:01 240

WinRM           129         28/08/2012 07:30:01 98

MSExchange CmdletLogs   6   28/08/2012 07:30:01 96Event Details: Échec de la cmdlet. Cmdlet Get-User, paramètres {Identity=NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM}.

Disk            11          28/08/2012 07:00:03 1

SharePoint Foundation   6398    28/08/2012 04:31:17 1

Windows Server Update Serv  13032   28/08/2012 03:33:31 4

DCOM            10016           28/08/2012 00:52:39 9

SharePoint Foundation   5586    28/08/2012 00:00:06 1

SharePoint Foundation   5767    27/08/2012 12:00:57 1

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's not a large amount of detail in your question regarding the errors apart from their event IDs.

I did see 6398, 5586 and 5767 though, and I recall seeing these a couple of days ago on an SBS 2011 server I was maintaining.

Please check for a message about proc_UpdateStatisticsNVP. If your message contains this, then you may find the following link useful.

http://blog.scuzz.ca/?p=66

In regards to the 10016 error, this is pretty common on SBS 2011 post install, and the following link may assist with this.

http://halfloaded.com/blog/sbs-2011-distributedcom-eventid-10016-fixed/

Hopefully these point you in the right direction.